# Picture as background

Tags: css

I have a picture as background. Before I had a scroll bar, and now it is gone. That is what I wanted.

The problem i'm facing now is is:

1. On the desktop, it does not show my whole picture. For example the cup and on the mobile, my picture is cut in half.

What can I do to have the whole picture as background on desktop and mobile?

This is the homepage: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/DBS/DBS.php

And try to view it on a mobile device, so you can see what I mean.

My css

```
    /* CSS Dokument */
    body{
       background: url(baggrund.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%`? But the image will shrink. Setting only `background-size: 100%` will show full image, but it won't cover the whole div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix the cropping of your image:

```
body {
  background: url(baggrund.jpg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

But now the Image wont fill the whole background. The problem is not the in the code. You try to use one image to fit on all possible resolutions. Thats not possible without some negativ aspects, like cropping.

You will need at least three different images for breakpoints like mobile, tablet and desktop.

Try to read a little about responsive webdesign and media queries.

http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But, when I take center center fixed away, and only use no-repeat, I can scroll again, and that is not good. :D As you can se now: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/DBS/DBS.php

Comment: I dont see any scrollbars on chrome, safari and FF. I see some white spaces when i try to scroll in chrome and safari, but this is webkit "feature" ;) 
looks the same like before, just without stretching the image (i added center center fixed and cover again via devtools). 
But anyways you will need more images and breakpoints ;)

Comment: Sorry, if I ask too much. But I just starting to program. But the problem is that I dont what to have the white spaces, when I scroll. The background picture is the only picture that I want, that is why I dont want the white spaces, when I scroll, but only that the picture is static and fast :D

Comment: You can set a background color to avoid the white spaces, but thats a browser thing, so you cant do anything about it ;) Check it on Firefox ;)
Your backgroundimage is fine, but you need it in more resolutions to server other devices. read the links i posted ;)

you can use  overflow-x: hidden if it suits you.